# C segmentation fault when printing single linked list using pointer to pointer of first node(head node)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Aim : Create a single linked list and print the list using HEAD POINTER (not the HEAD NODE).

`**start`:

- is the HEAD NODE (FIRST NODE) pointer
- instead of storing HEAD NODE(FIRST NODE) as `*start`, I want to store HEAD NODE pointer as `**start`.

ALG:

1. create list with five nodes (hard coded in my program).
2. display them using pointer to HEAD NODE

There is a significant HOLE in the code, which do not appear easily.
Could anyone give your inputs on this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
        int data;
        struct node *link;
}**start;


void display(void) {
        struct node *p;

        if (!strart ) { printf("List is empty\n"); return; }
        p = *start;
        printf("List :");
        while(p != NULL) {
                printf("-%d", p->data);
                p = p->link;
        }
        puts("");
}

struct node **createlist(void) {
        int n;
        struct node *p, *new, *tmp; 

        printf("enter no of elements to add\n");
        //scanf("%d", &n);

        p = NULL;
        n=5;
        while(n--) {
                new = (struct node *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct node)); 
                new->data = n;
                if (p) {
                        p->link = new;
                        p = new;
                } else if (p == NULL) {
                        p = tmp = new;
                }
        }
        printf("before assign start :%p\n", start);
        start = &tmp;
        printf("after assign start :%p\n", start);
        printf("In create List :\n");
        display();

        return start; 
}
int main() {

        int ch;
        do {
                printf("1.CreateList 2.DisplayList\n");
                //scanf("%d", &ch); //HARDCODED

                switch(1) {
                        printf("switch -> start :%p\n", start);
                        case 1 : start = createlist();
                        printf("after create -> start :%p\n", start);
                        case 2 : printf("Disp:\n"); display(); break;
                        default : printf("Invalid option\n");
                }
        } while(0);

        return 0;
}
```

Output of code:

```
root@CDrive:~/datastructures# ./a.out 
1.CreateList 2.DisplayList
enter no of elements to add
before assign start :(nil)
after assign start :0x7ffd13e64798
In create List :
List :-4-3-2-1-0
after create -> start :0x7ffd13e64798
Disp:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Use `valgrind`.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: `struct node **createlist(void)` returning a pointer to pointer makes little sense here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you assign `start` the address of a temporary, function-local object:

```
   start = &tmp;
```

Later you return that address:

```
    return start;
```

From this point the returned pointer points to an object that no longer exists.

It's not clear to me why you have declared `start` as a `struct node **`. You say that:

> **start: is the HEAD NODE (FIRST NODE) pointer

... but it's not. `**start` is a node, not a pointer. `*start` *could* be made to point at the first node. `start` is declared as a pointer to a pointer to a node.

> instead of storing HEAD NODE(FIRST NODE) as *start, I want to store HEAD NODE pointer as **start

You can't; as declared, it's not the right type. `**start` is a node, you can't store a node pointer in it. `*start` is a pointer to node, and `start` is a pointer to a pointer to a node.

I really think `start` should be probably be declared as a `struct node *` and not a `struct node **`. You seem to misunderstand what the double-star means.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises here
With the return of the function createlist() the stack frame of it is destroyed and even variable temp is also destroyed. So temp variable is no more and we have the address of first node of list is in temp so the value *start becomes zero in the main function and accessing elements there is always a segmentation fault.

```
    start = &tmp;
    printf("after assign start :%p\n", start);
    printf("In create List :\n");
    display();
```

To overcome this use a global head pointer to hold the address of first node or you can have the tmp variable as global .